# AWS Increase maps and reducers using Hadoop API

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, mapreduce

I am running WordCount example on AWS server. I want to test my output and analyze them. I want to increase the no. of mappers and no. of reducers and also no. of chunks.

How can I achieve the same ?

Do I have to set the no. of mappers/reducers while creating a job ? or I have to add some code ? I am using java.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the number of mappers and reducers in the main function of your Java program that starts the MapReduce job using JobConf's `conf.setNumMapTasks(int num)` and `conf.setNumRedTasks(int num)`, respectively.

For the mapper, note the following from the [api:](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html#setNumMapTasks%28int%29)

`"This is only a hint to the framework. The actual number of spawned map tasks depends on the number of InputSplits generated by the job's InputFormat.getSplits(JobConf, int). A custom InputFormat is typically used to accurately control the number of map tasks for the job."`

Explicitly setting the number of input chunks is a bit more difficult. The way the input is split up is determined by the `InputFormat` you use and the corresponding `InputSplits` that it uses. You will have to make your own custom InputFormat/InputSplits if you wish to manipulate the way the input is split.